# acl url_regex on squid3 is not working using an online tested regular expression

Tags: proxy, regex, squid

I was asked to block Facebook access from 8:00am to 3:00pm for almost all users but them are using **alternative Facebook URLs** to access the social network anyway. This is consuming a lot of our low bandwidth and we can't even work. I decided to design a **regular expression (regex) to parse these URLs and block them**. I don't want to block all facebook URLs but only alternatives. An alternative Facebook URLs mostly contains the words **prod** or **iphone**. The next ones are alternative Facebook URLs registered by our proxy server:

```
m.iphone.touch.prod.facebook.com
m.iphone.haid.prod.facebook.com:443
m.ct.prod.facebook.com
m.vi-vn.prod.facebook.com
```

The designed regex: `/((?=.*\biphone\b)|(?=.*\bprod\b)).*\.facebook\.com(\:|\d|)/`

I tested this regex on https://regex101.com/ and https://www.regextester.com. The regex is **matching** for:

```
m.iphone.touch.prod.facebook.com
m.iphone.haid.prod.facebook.com:443
m.ct.prod.facebook.com
m.vi-vn.prod.facebook.com
```

And is **not matching** for:

```
www.facebook.com
m.facebook.com
mqtt.facebook.com (for purple-facebook)
graph.facebook.com
connect.facebook.com
3-edge-chat.facebook.com
```

So far this is what I wanted, alternative URLs blocked and regular Facebook URLs allowed. **My regex looks good to be used in squid**.

Next step is to modify the file /etc/squid3/squid.conf by adding a new acl pointing the file that contains the regex:

```
acl facebook dstdom_regex "/etc/squid3/acl/facebook" //The file contains the regex
http_access deny pass facebook
```

When I run **squid3 -k parse** for check the configuration file I am getting the errors:

```
2017/09/22 11:12:26| Processing: acl facebook dstdom_regex "/etc/squid3/acl/facebook"
2017/09/22 11:12:26| squid.conf line 78: acl facebook dstdom_regex "/etc/squid3/acl/facebook"
2017/09/22 11:12:26| aclParseRegexList: Invalid regular expression '((?=.*\biphone\b)|(?=.*\bprod\b)).*\.facebook\.com(\:|\d|)': Invalid preceding regular expression
2017/09/22 12:39:33| Warning: empty ACL: acl facebook dstdom_regex "/etc/squid3/acl/facebook"
```

Obviously, the squid3 parser is tagging my acl as **wrong**, but I already tested online and it was good to use. Also it says the acl is empty. What does this mean? The acl was declared with the name **facebook**. I am very confused at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the regex. Changed the regex with this one: `\b(iphone|prod)\b.*\.facebook\.com` and now squid is stopping the URLs. After running `squid3 -k parse` squid says there is no problem, and if an user is trying to access to an alternative Facebook link such as (for instance): test.prod.facebook.com the proxy refuses the connection.